# iOS background queue retrieving data twice?

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to increase the responsiveness of my app and while checking out the debugger console I've noticed that the app seems to be retrieving XML data twice . . . that is, when the page appears, I dispatch a background queue to go fetch some xml data, parse it, and return an array of objects. I type out the data string in the console using nslog, and for some reason It's printing it out twice. Heres my relevant code:

In the VC:

```
-(void)startBackgroundQueue{
dispatch_async(backgroundThread, ^(void){
    SDJConnection *connection = [[SDJConnection alloc]init];
    self.dataArray = [connection getVideoData];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"tube_data_loaded" object:nil];
    });
}
```

the getVideoData method in SDJConnection looks like this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getVideoData {

NSURL *dataURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/dancingastronaut/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=10"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:dataURL];

NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data string: %@",dataString);

YouTubeParser *parser = [[YouTubeParser alloc]initWithData:data];
[parser setDelegate:parser];

[parser parse];

    return [parser videosArray];

}
```

and then the VC performs this code:

```
-(void)backgroundQueueDone{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(void){
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    if ([_dataArray count] >1) {
        self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        [self.tableView reloadData];}                
});
}
```

Im not sure if this is a problem or not, but I'm worried I'm wasting resources by somehow running thru this twice. Any ideas on what might be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you called your method "startBackgroundQueue" twice? In my humble opinion the block would be executed once.

And why you use notification to get the result of the block? You can use nested blocks like:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundThread, ^(void){
    SDJConnection *connection = [[SDJConnection alloc]init];
    self.dataArray = [connection getVideoData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(void){
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        if ([self.dataArray count] >1) {
            self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            [self.tableView reloadData];}                
    });
});
```

That saves you the complete notification ;)